# Use GitHub Actions to create a tag but not a release

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions, git-tag, github-release

Currently on my GitHub repository, I have the following workflow that releases a nightly snapshot every day, and uses the current date as release name and tag name:

```yaml
name: Nightly Snapshot

on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "59 23 * * *"

jobs:
  build:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      - name: Checkout branch "master"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'master'
      - name: Release snapshot
        id: release-snapshot
        uses: actions/create-release@latest
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
          release_name: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```

GitHub labels all snapshots created this way as the latest release. However, I want to avoid this, and achieve something akin to [what Swift's snapshots are like](https://github.com/apple/swift/releases): the snapshots are only tags; although they appear among the releases, they're treated differently.

How should I modify my workflow file to make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Another option is to use [GitHub Script](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-script). This creates a lightweight tag called `<tagname>` (replace this with the name of your tag):

```yaml
      - name: Create tag
        uses: actions/github-script@v5
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.git.createRef({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              ref: 'refs/tags/<tagname>',
              sha: context.sha
            })
```

Comment: `tagname` will contain the value used for naming your tag

Comment: On a different note is it possible to do a Release from a specific Branch or Tag, i have used the above and it always creates a Release from Master/Main Branch, i even checked out the Relevant Branch/Tag Before this step but no luck!

Comment: @MohammedAli maybe you are running this workflow with a filter for master/main branch only or maybe you are passing the wrong SHA?

Comment: does it need PAT?    `github-token: ${{ secrets.MY_PAT }}`

Comment: Note that the job needs the correct permissions (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions)

Comment: In case some one wants to know how to pass tag name variable in, this works for me `ref: 'refs/tags/${{ inputs.tag_name }}',`

Comment: Note that the same code works with `actions/github-script@v6`.

Comment: Note that if you use this mention with the GITHUB_TOKEN instead of a PAT or Deploy Key, tag generation will work but it will not trigger any other workflows that use on.push.tags triggers. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27028 for why.

Comment: What would be the equivalent of an annotated type tag? I guess it differs from the lightweight no?

Comment: In case you have a permission error, adding 
```
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Answer (score 11):

Edit: Michael Ganß's solution is better.

---

I found [this GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/commit-tagger) that tags on demand. Using it, my workflow can be revised as such:

```yaml
name: Nightly Snapshot

on:
  schedule:
  - cron: "59 23 * * *"

jobs:
  tag:
    name: Tag
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get current date
        id: date
        run: echo "::set-output name=date::$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')"
      - name: Checkout branch "master"
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: 'master'
      - name: Tag snapshot
        uses: tvdias/github-tagger@v0.0.1
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          tag: ${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
```

Comment: Possible alternative: https://github.com/simpleactions/create-tag

Comment: Michael Ganß's solution uses GitHub's own API directly, instead of through a 3rd party action.

Answer (score 5):

I succeed with only :  git tag + git push
I'm using gitVersion to automatically generate the tag

```yaml
  semver:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.7
        with:
          versionSpec: '5.x'
      - name: Determine Version
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.7
      - name: Display SemVer
        run: |
          echo "SemVer: $GITVERSION_SEMVER" && echo "$version" && echo "$major.$minor.$patch"
      - name: Create git tag
        run: |
          git tag $GITVERSION_SEMVER
      - name: Push git tag
        run: git push origin $GITVERSION_SEMVER
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on Michael Ganß's solution, here is an example of how to create a variable dynamically.

```
- name: Set Dist Version
  run: |
    BUILD_NUMBER="${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_number }}-${{ github.run_attempt }}"
    echo "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    VERSION="$(mvn -q -U -Dexpression=project.build.finalName help:evaluate -DforceStdout=true -DbuildNumber=${BUILD_NUMBER})"
    echo "DIST_VERSION=${VERSION}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- name: Create Tag
  uses: actions/github-script@v6
  with:
    script: |
      const {DIST_VERSION} = process.env          
      github.rest.git.createRef({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          ref: `refs/tags/${DIST_VERSION}`,
          sha: context.sha
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Scot's method, maybe encounter `Resource not accessible by integration` error. Here's the [solution](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/60820#discussioncomment-6445895)

```yaml
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all // set permission
    - name: Create Tag
      uses: actions/github-script@v6
      with:
        script: |
          github.rest.git.createRef({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              ref: 'refs/tags/v${{ steps.extract-version.outputs.VERSION }}',
              sha: context.sha
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my github action code to create git tag and push

```
  - name: Create Tag
    uses: rickstaa/action-create-tag@v1.7.2
    with:
      tag: my_tag_name
```

Read more about this at https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-update-tag